# React.useEffect not working in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

The state does not seem to change or rerender. I have tried logging from inside the useEffect and nothing happens. Any idea how to get the useEffect working?

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('bots/burrito', function(req, res, next) {
    //res.render('bot')
    res.render('bot')
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  console.log(err)
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

bot.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const tutorials=(props)=>{
    const [a, setA] = React.useState('asdf')
    React.useEffect( ()=>{
       setA('asdfasfdasdfa')
    }, [] );
    return(
        <p>{a}</p>
    )
 }


module.exports = tutorials;
```

When I navigate to `https://localhost:3000/bots/burrito` I see the rendered `<p>asdf</p>` and it never changes.

Comment: If you are doing Server Side Rendering the `useEffect` hook won't work. I just did a quick google search.... there are answers. I'm not familiar with SSR enough to suggest any of them though.

Comment: You are just returning the rendered html from the server, not the react script itself.

Answer (score 1):

`express-react-views` calls [`ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) under the hood.  that function returns the initial HTML for your component and does not attempt to apply hooks, as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85):

> If you use server rendering, keep in mind that neither useLayoutEffect nor useEffect can run until the JavaScript is downloaded.