# Use React+D3 in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, d3.js

I am trying to use D3 in a React component *within an Express app*. It seems like it should be a rather easy task, but following various tutorials not targeted to an Express app did not work: in the example below, I get an empty svg (`<!DOCTYPE html><div><p>D3 Example</p><svg></svg></div>`) without the red circle.

A possible explanation is that `React.useEffect` [does not run on server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638562/5599687). However, I do not understand why this does not run *after* the Javascript is loaded. In any case, I cannot find how to work around this problem, so any help to understand it better or a solution will be appreciated :)

---

I list my relevant code below. I am rather new with Node, so I tried to stick to Express example conventions.

#### app.js

```
var simulationRouter = require('./routes/simulation');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());
...
app.use('/simulation', simulationRouter);
```

#### routes/simulation.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('d3_show_nolib');
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### views/d3_show_nolib.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { select } from "d3";

export default function App() {
  const svgRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);
    const getData = () => {
      svg
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("stroke", 1.5);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>D3 Exemple</p>
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(I expect this to work as the following single html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg id='svg'></svg>

    <script>
      var svg = d3.select('#svg');

      svg.attr('width', 100)
         .attr('height', 100);
      svg
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("stroke", 1.5)
        .attr('cx', 10)
        .attr('cy', 10);
    </script>

  </body>


</html>
```

)

Comment: As you stated, `useEffect` does not run on the server, but **express-react-views** only renders on the server -- quote from the official doc: "I'm saying it again to avoid confusion: this does not do anything with React in the browser. This is only a solution for server-side rendering." You may want to take a look at Nextjs.